# Simple guessing game number of turns

Tags: python

New to programming and Python. I was making a simple guessing game and wanted to make maximum number of turns 3. When I run the program and guess the number correctly, it still keep the while loop running. I want to terminate the program when the guess is right. Any help would be appreciated!

```
secret_number = 9
attempts = 0
while attempts <= 2:
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))
    if guess == secret_number:
        print("Yes you succeeded!")
    else:
        print("You failed!")
        attempts = attempts + 1
```

I was expecting to finish the game when the guess is right!

Comment: Use `break` to terminate the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I added in "break" and "else" into your codes, so that the game is ended with 2 more appropriate message

```
secret_number = 9
attempts = 0
while attempts <= 2:
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))
    if guess == secret_number:
        print("Yes you succeeded!")
        print("Mission Completed")
        break
    else:
        print("You failed!")
        attempts = attempts + 1

else:
    print("Running out of attempts. Game is terminated now")
```